# Yii multiple relations

Tags: php, yii

In my database I have 5 tables:

- game(game_id,name,...)
- tag (tag_id,name,...)
- collection (coll_id,name,...)
- collections_tags (id,coll_id,tag_id)
- game_tag (id,game_id,tag_id)

Every game has many tags, collection has many tags. If i take a collection, I can find its games using the collection's tags.

I'm trying to perform this task with yii relations:

```
//in Collection's relations:
 'tags'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tag',  'collections_tags(coll_id,tag_id)'),  
 'games'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Game','tag_id', 'through'=>'tags')
```

Then I get a $collection and try this:

```
 echo "collection ".$collection->name.": (id=".$collection->coll_id.") has ".count($collection->tags)."tags\n";
echo count($coll->games);//error here
```

and get an error
What is wrong in the relations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you may see here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through, the correct declaration of that relation would be as follows:

```
 'games'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Game', array('tag_id'=>'id'), 'through'=>'tags')
```

Comment: In the example you gave me (at yiiframework.com) they use "Role" model. Is it necessary to use collections_tags model in my case? Or there is some workaround without crearing a new class?

Comment: It may not be necessary, but if there is a way, it would be pretty tough and you would have to dig in the framework's AR code. You can find the following "principle" in the documentation: "Before we use AR to perform relational query, we need to let AR know how one AR class is related with another". So AR works with models. That's how it is.