# Yii relation doesn't work well with array('FK'=>'PK')

Tags: php, yii

In addition to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313259/yii-multiple-relations) I have relations in Collection model like this :

```
'games'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Game', array('game_id'=>'game_id'), 'through'=>'game_tags')
```

But in each place I insert array('FK'=>'PK') pattern the query contains JOIN..ON() - the condition is empty.

If I write:

```
'games'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Game', 'game_id', 'through'=>'game_tags')
```

I get `ON(games.game_id=game_tags.id)`
What is wrong in the relation?
I apologize for sending you to my previous question for further explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a version problem. I had Yii v1.1.7, the given syntax of relation is introduces in 1.1.9.
So be careful.